# login form works if fields are empty?

Tags: php, forms

i have setup an internal site for logging in a few users, users wont change and pw wil be done by authorised people only.

so i needed something VERY simple and without using a database where possible.

so i made the following script, works well except one of my testers tried to login with both fields empty... and it worked??

cant figure it out.

login

```
    <form id="slick-login" action="_login_action.php" method="post">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" class="placeholder" placeholder="username"/>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" class="placeholder" placeholder="password"/>

<input type="submit" value="Login" />
```

_login_action.php

```
    <?php
$usernames = array("admin", "user", "guest", "input");
$passwords = array("admin123", "user123", "guest123", "input123");
$page = "index.php";
for($i=0;$i<count($usernames);$i++){
  $logindata[$usernames[$i]]=$passwords[$i];
}
if($logindata[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"]){
session_start();
$_SESSION["username"]=$_POST["username"];
header('Location: '.$page);
exit;
}else{
header('Location: login.php?wrong=1');
exit;
}
?>
```

this is the file that i include on the pages i need protecting;

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])&& !empty($_SESSION['username'])){
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Are you suppressing errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more check needed:

```
if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && $logindata[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"])
```

Comment: where would i put the check?